# How to add url with interpolation as the value of the input textbox?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I try to add url with interpalation inside input text:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter code" value="'https://varip.geodata.com/?code='" + {{ mycode }} />
```

but on the row above I get this error:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '+' is not a valid attribute name.
```

My question how to add url with interpolation as the value of the input textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use normal JS expression inside `""`, and remember to add `:` at the beginning of your prop before using JS expression

```
:value="'https://varip.geodata.com/?code=' + mycode"
```

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter code"
  :value="'https://varip.geodata.com/?code=' + mycode"
/>
```